# mySQL SELECT * and group concat

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL query, which works well. Is there a way I can aslo `SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS` with this query though? I'm struggling with syntax.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tc.`name` ORDER BY tc.entity_id) AS cat_ids
FROM products AS tp
JOIN categories AS tc
ON FIND_IN_SET(tc.entity_id, tp.category_ids) 
GROUP BY tp.category_ids;
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
SELECT tp.*, GROUP_CONCAT(tc.`name` ORDER BY tc.entity_id) AS cat_ids
FROM products AS tp
JOIN categories AS tc
ON FIND_IN_SET(tc.entity_id, tp.category_ids) 
GROUP BY tp.category_ids;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have given the `products` table the alias "tp". You can access columns from the `products` table using `tp.columnName`, or all columns by using `tp.*`

```
SELECT tp.* 
FROM products AS tp
JOIN categories AS tc
ON FIND_IN_SET(tc.entity_id, tp.category_ids) 
GROUP BY tp.category_ids;
```

Comment: Where is the `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Comment: @Barmar If Liam is asking for `products.*`, then he's not asking to do a `GROUP CONCAT` He is specifically trying to get all the info from one table, and not the other.

Comment: He says he wants to get all the info from the `products` table, **in addition to** the category information that he's already getting.